# Shrink down row numbers in a Pandas Dataframe when removing rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Essentially this is the same question as in this link:[How to automatically shrink down row numbers in R data frame when removing rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361471/how-to-automatically-shrink-down-row-numbers-in-r-data-frame-when-removing-rows). However, I want to do this with a pandas dataframe. How would I go about doing so? There seems to be nothing similar to the rownames method of R dataframes in the Pandas library...Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call "row number" is part of the index in pandas-speak, in this case a integer index. You can rebuild the index using

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Is there any other way? The thing is let's say I add one new entry, and then another. Then I decide to delete the first new entry that I added, but add it back, it gives me an error since I'm building a new index. I want to keep the old index always, not build a new one. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Never mind I just dropped the new column that is created, this works well thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing this, which does not generate a new column with the old index:

```
df.index=range(len(df.index))
```